# Using a trigger on a table after any modification to copy affected row into a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb

I would like to create a trigger to this example table when I insert, update or delete any row into the table. I have never worked with triggers before so this will be my first one.

I have this code so far:

```
  DROP TRIGGER auditemployees
CREATE TRIGGER auditemployees AFTER INSERT ON employees

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO employees_trigger select * from employees where emp_no = NEW.emp_no;
END;
```

**The problem now is:**

I would like to copy the affected row into another table in this case employees_trigger, but in order to copy the whole row and to pass the values all I can think of is using variables for each field which in my opinion sounds inefficient since if I had 50 fields I will have to use 50 variables and then insert all those values into the new table.

Is there any better and efficient way to do this?

Also I get the error:

```
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER auditemployees AFTER INSERT ON
> employees
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every statement needs to be terminated -- there is no `;` at the end of the `DROP` statement.

You are missing a `DELIMITER` statement, and you are not using a different delimiter for the `CREATE`.

What's wrong with `OLD.*` for the 50 variables?